# Fatal error when accessing widgets.php: "Uncaught TypeError: array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, null given"

Tags: php, wordpress

It just happened now that when I want to access widgets section from the backend, it shows

"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

*Thanks @Dawid Frankiewicz for debug instruction.

Here it is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, null given in /.../wp-content/themes/.../inc/template-tags.php:167 Stack trace: 

#0 /.../wp-content/themes/.../template-tags.php(167): array_merge(NULL, Array) 

#1 /.../wp-content/themes/.../widgets/featured-posts-slider-widget.php(171): theme_append_excluded_duplicate_posts(Object(WP_Query)) 

#2 /.../wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php(393): theme_featured_posts_slider_widget->widget(Array, Array) 

#3 /.../wp-includes/widgets.php(2022): WP_Widget->display_callback(Array, Array) 

#4 /.../wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-widgets-controller.php(697): wp_render_widget('colormag_featur...', 'colormag_front_...') 

#5 /.../wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-widgets-controller.php(154): WP_REST_Widgets_Controller->prepare_item_for_response(Array, Object(WP_REST_Request)) 

#6 /.../wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1143): WP_REST_Widgets_Controller->get_items(Object(WP_REST_Request)) 

#7 /.../wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(990): WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request(Object(WP_REST_Request), '/wp/v2/widgets', Array, NULL) 

#8 /../wp-includes/rest-api.php(519): WP_REST_Server->dispatch(Object(WP_REST_Request)) 

#9 /.../wp-includes/rest-api.php(2868): rest_do_request(Object(WP_REST_Request)) 

#10 [internal function]: rest_preload_api_request(Array, '/wp/v2/widgets?...') 

#11 /.../wp-includes/block-editor.php(601): array_reduce(Array, 'rest_preload_ap...', Array) 

#12 /.../wp-admin/widgets-form-blocks.php(26): block_editor_rest_api_preload(Array, Object(WP_Block_Editor_Context)) 

#13 ./../wp-admin/widgets.php(32): require('/home/sitename...') 

#14 {main} thrown in /.../wp-content/themes/theme-name/inc/template-tags.php on line 167
```

Comment: Try installing `classic widgets` plugin

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to help you. Put this in wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

After you add this go to widgets section again and look for error message. Then just paste this error here (if any appears), maybe we can help you.

Comment: Hi, I did it as you wrote, thanks! and the error are tons (in the edited question)... but they all seem to relate to rest api - should I disable it, delete it or something?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  This is not an answer, rather it's a comment. Incomplete and poor answers could get down votes.  (just saying)

Comment: @HowardE I know this, but I have not unlocked comments on questions yet (need 50 rep), can't really help otherwise. Or can I somehow?

Comment: @Asianewswire you can try deleting `template-tags.php` file in `/.../wp-content/themes/theme-name/inc/template-tags.php` via FTP. Remember to make a copy of a file. I don't know what this file is responsible for, but this file causes an error.

If you can paste `template-tags.php` file code somewhere, maybe i can fix it.

Comment: @Dawid Frankiewicz - will try now, thanks in advance